# Minecraft offline produces black screen

Tags: 13.04, minecraft

When I try to play Minecraft offline it says `Updating Minecraft...` and then I get a black screen. No error is displayed. I am using the Minecraft laucher jar file. Are there any packages I need to download in order to play Minecraft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A black screen can sometimes be caused by the LWJGL files being out of date, however if you can play your minecraft online this solution will not help you.

**Update your LWJGL Files:**

```
sudo apt-get install liblwjgl-java
```

Or you can take a look at this [link](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Update_LWJGL_%28Legacy%29) if the above does not work.

You could also consider installing [OpenJDK 7](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/openjdk-7-jre/)

Please note that you have to run minecraft online at least once for it to run offline.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you installed a mod. You also deleted the META-INF folder. Rename/remove your .minecraft folder and re-try, it WILL work if the META-INF folder is present. The lwjgl files have been updated in mc1.6, so that is not the problem.